# How to add image URL from storage to realtime database in android kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload image reference to realtime database from storage but I'm getting an error as: "Object does not exist at location".

This is the code for uploading images to storage as well as database

```
private lateinit var firebaseStore: FirebaseStorage
private lateinit var database: FirebaseDatabase
private lateinit var storageReference: StorageReference

database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
firebaseStore = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images")

private fun uploadImageToDatabase() {
        storageReference.child("images" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()).putFile(filePath)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                storageReference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                    println("*************$it*************")
                    database.reference.child("images").setValue(it.path.toString()).addOnSuccessListener {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Images Uploaded...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
                    }
                }.addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error in database: ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                })
            }.addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error in storage: ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })
    }
```

This println statement is never getting executed.

Attached are the screenshots of storage and realtime database from firebase

[firebase storage image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQnGQ.png)

[realtime database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPXts.png)

Also, can anyone tell me the difference between these 3:

```
private lateinit var firebaseStore: FirebaseStorage
private lateinit var database: FirebaseDatabase
private lateinit var storageReference: StorageReference

database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
firebaseStore = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images")
```

Comment: Is any of the failure messages displayed?

Comment: yes, "Error in database: Object does not exists at location"

Comment: Have you tried to use something like this `.child("images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg")`?

Comment: But I don't want to store only .jpg images. I want to store all types of images.

Comment: In that case, have you tried to specify the corresponding file extension?

Comment: no. how should I do that?

Comment: Yes, give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Could you please write the code to specify file extension?

Comment: It's present in one of the comments above.

Comment: I tried the above code but still getting the same error.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. The problem was that it was taking few seconds to upload the url to the database. So, I added a 5 sec delay and it worked.